# Local TFS 2013: Continuous Integration of a web service to Azure doesn't update. No signs of anything happening

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild

with a local TFS 2013 server i'm trying to implement the Continuous Integration of a webservice to Azure.  Now the build Definitions have the following:

/t:Publish /p:DeloyOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="xxx" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:UserName="yyy\$zzz" /p:Password="abc"

When a checkin occurs the build gets triggered, and i receive an Successful message.  I then access the site on azure only to find the site wasn't updated.

i don't receive any errors.  it almost seems like the deploy didn't happen.
if i do all this manually using the publish feature of VS2013, i choose the profile i got from importing the 'publish profile' file from azure. Then i see the changes.  So my profile is good.  It's just seems that the MSBuild is not doing the deploy after the build.

also in the LOG of the build.  i don't see any references to deploying... not sure if i should see something there.

the only hint i get from the log is that the line: 
Run optional script after MSBuild = 00:00
everything after that is also 00:00.

is there perhaps a setting that the autobuild needs to deploy?  something more than what the manual publish would need?

Comment: Which build template are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this odd problem was happening because the username included the domain.   now there are several guides out there that indicate to use the user name found in the publish file you down load from azure. Which is what I did. But the web deploy didn't work until the domain was removed from the username.

/flp:verbosity="diagnostic" /p:DeloyOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="xxx" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:UserName="$zzz" /p:Password="abc"

notice the removal of yyy in username from the first post.

now i'm happily deploying.